# Bootstrap Input Mask is not Working in Dynamic Textboxes? What can i do?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, date, jquery-inputmask

I tried this code also.But didnt get the out.

```
$(document).on("focus", ".date-picker", function () {       
   $(".date-picker").inputmask("dd-mm-yyyy", {"placeholder": "dd-mm-yyyy"});       
});
```

Comment: instead of `$(".date-picker")` try `$(this)`

Comment: I tried that also....:(

Comment: getting any errors in console???

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function   [ undefined function input mask]

Comment: this means `inputmask` method is not defined in boostrap or you are using it wrongly.

Comment: refer this http://bootstrapvalidator.com/examples/mask/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try Using Jquery Mask instead on Bootsrtap input masking...It works very well

```
$("#btn").click( function (){       
       $("#content").append('<input class="date" type="text"></input>');       
    $(".date").mask("99/99/9999");       
});         
$(".date").focus( function (){       
      $(".date").mask("99/99/9999");      
});
```

[Working Fiddle Demo] :http://jsfiddle.net/SEXAj/855/